# how to set text-decoration underline on hover over text area's each word

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to make a underline on each word in textarea when user hover over it after on click function on a button how can i do it?

```js
$('#popup_button').on("click", function(){
$('#my-content').css('cursor', 'help' );
$('#my-content span').hover(function() {
$('#my-content span').css("text-decoration", "underline");
});
});
```

Comment: A textarea only contains text. You would need to do that in some other element that holds html. Might consider using a `contenteditable` div instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit tricky and you need to use JavaScript to accomplish what you want.

I suggest using both [Jquery](http://jQuery%20https://jquery.com/) and [Lettering.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js)

You need also to use a contenteditable element instetad of a textarea. Unfortunately a contenteditable element cannot be used inside a form. So, before submitting your form you will have to read the value of the contenteditable element, strip HTML tags and set the value of a hidden textarea to that clean value.

Following you can find HTML, CSS and JS working code.

HTML:

```
<div id="my-content" contenteditable="true"></div>
<form action="some-page.php" onsubmit="return getContent()">
    <textarea id="my-textarea" style="display:none"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<span id="popup_button">click me!</span>
```

CSS:

```
#my-content {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#my-content:hover span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


#my-content.clicked:hover span {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

JS:
First import both jQuery and Lettering.js:

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lettering.js/0.7.0/jquery.lettering.min.js

  function getContent(){
            $("#my-textarea").val($("#my-content").attr("aria-label"));
          }

  ```
      function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement) {
          var range,selection;
              range = document.createRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
              range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
              range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
              selection = window.getSelection();//get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
              selection.removeAllRanges();//remove any selections already made
              selection.addRange(range);//make the range you have just created the visible selection
      }

      elem = document.getElementById('my-content');

      elem.addEventListener("keypress", function(evt) {
          var _evt = evt;
          setTimeout(function(){
            _evt = _evt || window.event;
            var charCode = _evt.keyCode || _evt.which;
            //if(charCode == 32) {
              $("#my-content").lettering('words');
              setEndOfContenteditable(elem);
            //}
          }, 10, _evt);
      }, false);

      $('#popup_button').on("click", function(){
          $('#my-content').css('cursor', 'help' );
          $('#my-content').addClass('clicked');
          $('#my-content span').hover(function() {
            $('#my-content span').css("text-decoration", "none");
            $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
          });
      });
  ```

[Here a working Codepen example.](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/Gbevyw)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: hey thanks for your help it is implementing fine, whenever i am hover over a word it shows underline but my problem is when user clicks on a button after then hovering over a word make it underlined. hope you understand my problem.

Comment: @gfdrth can you post your code somewhere so we can try to help you?

Comment: i have edited my above code. i am using your code plus the code i have edited above. problem is that whenever i am hovering over a word the entire sentence is underlined instead of each word

Comment: @gfdrth I have updated my code. Change a bit of your JS andd add a new CSS rule. Check it out: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/Gbevyw

Comment: thanks a lot... i have made some modification to your code and it works...thank you so much...

Comment: one more thing... when i hover over last word it underlined the last two words instead of only last word.

Comment: you're right, I just update the JS: removed the control on the space key and added a small delay to run the lettering function. Let me know if it works fine for you

Comment: Hey please help me through one more thing....how to count the no of words entered in div.

Comment: @gfdrth Pen updated: just use: $('#my-content').children().length